# Вставка текста из модального окна в родительское

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Допустим, у меня есть страница на ней есть форма, `textarea` и кнопка открыть окно. По нажатию на кнопку открывается окно(`window.open`). В нем тоже форма и кнопка Вставить. Допустим, я ввел в форму текст, нажал вставить и мне нужно, чтоб в родительском окне появился текст, который я ввел в форме модального окна. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что у mail.ru подсмотрели :) ?

Comment: @Deert вы имеете ввиду модальное окно или обычное?

>*** Модальное*** окно - это окно, не закрыв которое, он не может продолжать работу с родительским

Если модальное, то вам поможет стандартный метод обьекта window - prompt() ...

Answer (score 1):

Читаем про [window.parent](http://javascript.ru/window.parent).

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Иногда, даже теряюсь, что ответить. Ну, можно например так:

```
var newVal = "some_val";
window.parent.forms[0].['el_name'].value = newVal;
```

или в функцию передавать

```
window.parent.myFunc(newVal);
```

Comment: почитать то почитаю, но там кроме определения ничего нет.

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: @Deonis не parent а opener хранит ссылку на открывшее это окно окно

Answer (score 1):

После открытия окна туда можно передать все, что угодно, например, id нужного элемента

```
var newWindow = window.open(url);
newWindow.targetElement = document.getElementById('myId');
```

А в новом окне свободно обращаться к нему

```
var myVal = "value";
window.targetElement.value = myVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
        #text{
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var textWindow;
        function openWindow(){
            textWindow = window.open("","Введите текст:","top=100,left=100,width=400,height=200");
            textWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='Текст' id='input'>" +
                    "<input type='button' value='Ввести'" +
                    " onclick='window.opener.enter(document.getElementById(\"input\"))'>";        }
        function enter(textInput){
            var textOutput = document.getElementById("text");
            textOutput.value = textInput.value;
            textWindow.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Открыть окно" onclick="openWindow()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Это если окно не модальное а если надо модальное то используйте:

```
var text = prompt("Введите текст","Текст");
```

Comment: Нет, спасибо мне помог обыкновенная функция window.opener